# How can one put a dynamic attribute inside this jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this object..

```
$object = $(".service-box:first").attr("rel")
# => "spaghetti"
```

I am trying to find the this object inside of a selector..

```
$(".hqs-text[rel=$object]")
```

But this is an innapropriate way to use dynamic variables in this selector.

How can I do this correctly?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple concatenation will do:

```
$(".hqs-text[rel=" + $object + "]");
```

Or even all in one line:

```
$(".hqs-text[rel=" + $(".service-box:first").attr("rel") + "]");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hqs-text[rel="+$object+"]")
```